# Rejected retag edit

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

Yesterday I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786928/big-arrays-and-identifiers). It didn't say what language it was written in. I asked the OP, and he said in the comments that it was javascript. Between the time I asked him and I saw his response, it was tagged as [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). This morning, I submitted an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7787757). It was rejected, citing the reason

> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains.

Is my retagging wrong, when the author explicitly said the question was javascript?

Comment: But in the [next comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786928/big-arrays-and-identifiers#comment47728443_29786928) he said that he is making an applet. The OP probably doesn't know what language he is using :/

Comment: @user000001:  I've never heard of a "JavaScript applet".  I've heard of "Java applet", though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make more changes to the question.** There is more stuff to edit than just the tags.

Look, in [the revision](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7787757), you missed a lower-case I!

That said, the OP was likely mistaken on their tagging; they say that the question is in JavaScript but that's Java for sure.  Personally I think the tag was OK, but you *really* should fix more stuff.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. I submitted a similar [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7793551) later that was approved. Thanks anyway.